# awesome-wm gears.timer setup

Tags: timer, awesome-wm

I want to replace deprecated `awful.timer` with `gears.timer` in my `awesome-wm`. But I having trouble starting it. I took function from the [example](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/gears.timer.html) as a prototype and wrote simple test function. Here it is:

```
gears.timer {
    timeout   = 1,
    autostart = true,
    callback  = function()
        print("!!Timeout!!")
    end
}
```

I placed it in the end of the `rc.lua` file and ran `awesome`. From the look of the awesome-wm output it looks  like function never runs. How do I setup `gears.timer` so it runs?

P.S. I use this command to see the output of the `awesome-wm`:

```
DISPLAY=:0; Xephyr :1 -screen 800x600 -ac -br -noreset & \
DISPLAY=:1.0; sleep 1; awesome -c ~/.config/awesome/rc.lua
```

Comment: Which version of awesome are you using? Running awesome -v can tell you.

Comment: @UliSchlachter v4.0 Compiled against Lua 5.1.5 LGI version: 0.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome 4.0 only supports the timeout argument for `gears.timer`. The `autostart` argument and the `callback` argument are new in awesome 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make `gears.timer` work as a signal emitter:

```
timer = gears.timer {
    timeout   = 1
}

timer:connect_signal("timeout", function()
        print("!!Timeout!!")
    end
)

timer:start()
```

However I'm still a bit puzzled about usege of `autostart` and `callback` attributes.